# Entity Framework LINQ joining 5 tables on multiple columns (impossible?!)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, join, linq-to-entities

Please see image: [image]

I am trying to create a LINQ query that combines 5 different tables on 1 to 3 different columns.  I am basically taking the examples of 2 tables and repeating the join sections for tables 3 through 5.

UPDATE: how do I get the following LINQ query to work?????

```
    var match = (from t1 in context.cKNA1
                 join t2 in context.cKNB1 on 
                        new { t1.KUNNR, t1.RowId } equals 
                        new { t2.KUNNR, t2.RowId }
                 join t3 in context.cKNVV on 
                        new { t2.KUNNR, t2.RowId } equals 
                        new { t3.KUNNR, t3.RowId }
                 join t4 in context.cKNVH on 
                        new { t3.KUNNR, t3.RowId } equals 
                        new { t4.KUNNR, t4.RowId }
        SELECT ....columns here....)
```

I can't find anything online where there are more than 3 tables ***AND** 2 or more columns.

Comment: Wow! Don't believe in meaningful column names?

Comment: No it's not impossible.

Comment: Do you have any examples of these joins??? I can't seem to find them - I have resolved to just using a view to write these in SQL then adding them to EF, but it bothers me that linq can't do this on the fly.  HELP! :)

Comment: Did you even Google this? http://www.dotnetperls.com/join

Comment: You can use SelectMany (or multiple filtered "from" expressions if you're using query syntax).

Comment: @ta.speot.is  I did google this and I've only found examples where the join involves one column, or only  two tables, when I type in a third table intelli-sense does not indicate anything.  See update of the code for the above tables I want to run to get a join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write this query:

```
 var match = from t1 in context.cKNA1
             join t2 in context.cKNB1 on 
                    new { t1.KUNNR, t1.RowId } equals 
                    new { t2.KUNNR, t2.RowId }
             join t3 in context.cKNVV on 
                    new { t2.KUNNR, t2.RowId } equals 
                    new { t3.KUNNR, t3.RowId }
             join t4 in context.cKNVH on 
                    new { t3.KUNNR, t3.RowId } equals 
                    new { t4.KUNNR, t4.RowId }
    SELECT t1.KUNNR;
```

In fact, just remove the parenthesis. If it still doesn't work, the visual studio will mark one of those `join` words as error. If so, it means that the columns you are trying to link, have different data types.

Suppose that the VS mark the first `join` word as error. So, it means that `t1.KUNNR` and `t2.KUNNR` have different data types, or `t1.RowId` and `t2.RowId` have different data types.

Check and correct your data types, the problem will go away.

Comment: care to share an example where, say, t4 joins on fields from both t1 AND t3?